# how to get the value of array sent from AJAX POST in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am having a probelem with ajax multiple delete. I've sucessfully set the values of the checkbox slected in a variable.
the problem i have to solve is how to get the value of the sent array in php.
here is the ajax post code

```
<script>
    $("#delete-btn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = new Array();
        $(".check:checked").each(function() {
            id.push($(this).attr('value'));

        }); 
        $.post("../ajax/multiDelete.php",{id:id},function(data){
            alert(data);    
        });
    });
</script>
```

now, the php page

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $id = array($_POST['id']);

        foreach($id as $value){
                echo $value;    
        }
    }

?>
```

when the data is alerted, i only get "array";
i do not know about JSON, so if there is anything i can do without it then your help is most appreciated! thanks : D

Comment: do a `print_r($_POST['id'])` and see what you get

Comment: @slash197 , can't i echo with foreach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since id is an array and in your code you are wrapping it inside an array again.  Instead of that,do this :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
            // Don't use array($_POST['id']) as id is already an array
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            foreach($id as $value){
                    echo $value; 
                    // Here you'll get the array values   
            }
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want retun array from php - user json_encode()

```
echo json_encode(array($_POST['id']));
```

P.S. JS function alert() can`t print arrays or object. Use console.log(data) and you will see result in developer console of your browser.

Comment: He's asking for a JSON-free solution

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass array variable in AJAX. Convert id array to JSON using `JSON.stringify(id)`.

In PHP backend,use

```
<?php $val = json_decode($_REQUEST['id']); 
       foreach($val as $ids){
           echo $ids;
        }
```

use $val array to proceed further in php.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to your question, but I just wanted to show you a better way of getting the `id` values, without creating a new array variable and then pushing items into the array, by using the jQuery [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method:-

```
$("#delete-btn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get all the values in the array 'id' variable
    var id = $(".check:checked").map(function () {
        return this.value || 0;
    }).get();

    $.post("../ajax/multiDelete.php", { id: id }, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to access your checked value by-

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $id = array($_POST['id']);

        foreach($id as $value){
               foreach($value as $value1){
                echo $value1;    
        }
        }
    }

?>
```

Because this is an array inside array.